# 1990s post-apocalyptic independent movie with religious elements?

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

Ok, here is some hard one.

**Context:**

It is a movie I watched in late 1990s on TV. The movie itself was an American or German production from 1990s.
It was rather poorly made and it looked like an independent film.

**Plot:**

The movie was really weird. It was placed in post-apocalyptic setting.
The protagonist was a some kind of prophet, who went on a journey in order to write a new Bible. He also waited for a Second Coming. And there was a Satan.
I remember particularly one scene from this movie: someone (probably protagonist) sits on a barber seat when some satanic-like character walks around him saying "cut your hair".
Did I mention that the movie was weird?

**Things I vaguely remember :**

- I'm not sure but probably the music used in the movie was (black) metal.
- The protagonist was a young adult with long black hair
- Walking through desert

And no, I didn't confuse this movie with [black metal music videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sFdUicoaow).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [*Freedom Deep*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0367753/) (1998). I don't remember any specific scenes about a barber's chair but it certainly matches the other elements, especially the heavy metal music, post-apocalypse vibe and messianic Jesus-archetype hero with long black hair.

Comment: This is probably it. I'll check this later and confirm.

Comment: wha-?! wait, what just happened?

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza What do you mean?

Comment: @Kao - I assumed he was referring to the amazing cinematography and story-telling in the film.

Comment: @Kao - Yes, I was just marveling at how lucky we all are that this film even exists!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be *Left Behind* (2000)? I'm not entirely sure but it sounds similar if I'm thinking of the right movie.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0190524/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl):

> Rayford Steele is an airline pilot whose relationship with his wife has gone sour;he ponders having an affair with an attractive flight attendant, Hattie Durham. In the midst of a flight to London, a number of their passengers mysteriously disappear, and chaos takes hold as a number of vehicles on the ground and in the air are suddenly unmanned. Meanwhile, Buck Williams, a television journalist, is pondering the rash of sudden disappearances as he works on a report about Dr. Chaim Rosenzweig, an Israeli scientist who has devised a formula that would make any soil on earth easy to cultivate. However, Buck wonders if there's more to Rosenzweig than he first imagined when he discovers the doctor is in cahoots with two multi-millionaires who plan to broker the invention to promote their own agenda of international domination.

Comment: Why do you think this sounds similar? Can you provide some plot or something?